# MatTooltip Disappears Almost Immediately When Using MatTooltipClass

Tags: .net, angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material to display a tooltip like so:

```
<button
  mat-raised-button
  matTooltip="Line one&#13;line two..."
  matTooltipClass="tooltip"
  (click)="onOne()"
>
  One
</button>
<button
  mat-raised-button
  matTooltip="Line one&#13;line two..."
  (click)="onTwo()"
>
  Two
</button>
```

I have the tooltip style defined in the global css file:

```
.tooltip {
  background: #7d1c1c;
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

The tooltip on the Two button displays correctly with the default settings. The tooltip on button One displays with the modified style, but it disappears almost immediately.

This is a .NET project created using `dotnet new angular`. You can see a GIF of the problem and the code for the project [here](https://github.com/rmegal/dotnetcorengspa).

The tooltip using matTooltipClass works as expected in an Angular project created using `ng new`. I thought it might be related to Server Side Rendering (SSR), which the dotnet project uses, but the problem does not exist in the Angular project after migrating to SSR.

So, the problem only exists in the dotnet project. I've updated to the latest Angular/Material and the problem persists.

What am I missing?

Comment: I copied the code you provided into stackblitz and I'm not experiencing that issue. You might have something else at play here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvqeqw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-overview-example.css

Comment: Exactly. Like I said, it works in a pure Angular/Angular SSR project, but not dotnet. Open the solution in VS2019 and debug it there. Also, you must put the style in the global file (styles.scss in your case) for it to be used by matTooltipClass.

Comment: You could also use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` on your component instead of moving the .tooltip style to styles.scss to get it to apply.

Answer (score 1):

The dotnet angular template installs bootstrap, which is apparently messing with the Material Tooltip. Removing bootstrap (running `npm uninstall bootstrap` and deleting it from `styles` in angular.json) resolves the problem. That is, the matTooltipClass is applied without the tooltip immediately disappearing.

I'm using CSS Flexbox and Material in lieu of bootstrap so this is not an issue for me.

I got here by deleting the dotnet template generated app, replacing it with one generated by `ng new`. I then ran the app under VS2019 to ensure it worked. Finally, I compared the two and noticed the ng generated app was not installing all of the packages the dotnet templated app did. Bootstrap seemed to be the most likely candidate.

FYI I also tested this with a pure `ng new` app and installing bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap resulted in the same problem: the MatTooltip briefly displays and then disappears.

UPDATE: It just occurred to me that the name of the class might be the problem. I changed the style from `.tooltip` to `.testingclass` and the problem was resolved. I imagine using anything but `.tooltip` would be OK.

Comment: Thank you, changing .tooltip to .testingclass worked.